# What tool can be used to load test Website and Mobile Apps on Cloud (Azure)?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, performance-testing, azure-mobile-services, load-testing, loadrunner

I'm new to running load test. I have a question regarding load testing for Mobile Apps hosting on Azure.

- Can I use load runner to run load & performance test using HP LoadRunner for the mobile app on cloud? Any license required?
- Can I generate load from physical machine or does it have to be cloud load generator?
- How do I simulate different network condition such as slow 3G, fast 3G and 4G etc.?
- If HP LoadRunner is not suitable for this, what tool is being used to load test Websites and Mobile Apps on cloud? Please give a recommendation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can, current price would be [`$0.15` per virtual user per hour](https://software.microfocus.com/buy/stormrunner-load)
2. "Cloud" is nothing more than virtual machines which in their turn run on physical machines. Personally I prefer having physical where possible at this way you have confidence regarding hardware resources availability
3. It is built into LoadRunner, see [Speed Simulation for Mobile Vuser Scripts](https://lrhelp.saas.hpe.com/en/12.55/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/UI/ui_Network_Simulation.htm) for details.
4. HP LoadRunner seems suitable if you already have a license or budget. As an alternative you can consider [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) as it is:

   - Free and open source
   - Can be used on premise, in the cloud and any combination of load generator nodes
   - When it comes to websites testing JMeter can do whatever LoadRunner can do (if not more) including [different network speeds simulation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-simulate-different-network-speeds-your-jmeter-load-test)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm new to running load test.

Step 1, have your foundation skills assessed.  The question you are asking is one based upon architecture, which is a foundation class of knowledge for performance testers.  A shaky foundation here will cause severe problems down the road.

Step 2, invest in training.  Whatever tool you use, open source, commercial, homegrown, invest in the time to learn the tool.  Trying to master answering questions about an application at the same time you are attempting to master answering questions about your tool is as certain a path to no value as one exists in the performance testing field.

Step 3, you need a mentor.  If your management is unwilling to provide time for both training and access to a mentor working side by side with you on projects for a period then they are really not interested in your success.  They are interested in either the billing rate for this set of tasks or a check box that something has been done related to performance.  Neither of those options are good for your career or the application in the crosshairs.